# SMTP Mail Error, Failure Sending Mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, email, smtp

Im facing a problem when i want to sent email when to submit form. The problem is SMTP Mail error. when run it i get Message "Failure sending mail." and for the Innerexecption"Unable to connect to the remote server". below is my code:

<  Protected Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

```
    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

    Dim strConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("testConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=test;password=1234"
        conn.Open()





    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


    Dim sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()

    sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn


    Dim msg As MailMessage
    Dim email As String = String.Empty
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

    msg = New MailMessage()

    email = TextBox3.Text.Trim()
    'sender email address
    msg.From = New MailAddress("****s@gmail.com")
    'Receiver email address
    msg.[To].Add(email)
    msg.Subject = "Change Request have Been Submitted By:"
    msg.Body = "Hi " & TextBox1.Text.Trim() & "!" & vbLf & "Thanks for Submitted the Change Request Online " & vbLf & "Thanks!"
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("****s@gmail.com", "******")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.Send(msg)'THIS LINE IT SHOW THE ERROR'

    ' UserControl()
    Try
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Your Change Request have been submitted.');", True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " & ex.Message.ToString() & "');", True)
        Return
    Finally

        email = String.Empty
        sqlConn.Close()
        sqlComm.Dispose()
    End Try
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End Sub>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the wrong port number, google's gmail uses port 465, change the 587 and it should work (provided the username+password are correct).

Comment: yeah.. it work but i get another error at line 'msg.[To].Add(email)' the error {"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."}

Comment: @kolapopo what are you typing into the textbox? should be a standard email like: me@mydomain.com

Comment: i fix it @bensonsearch but not appear this  error on   'SmtpServer.Send(msg)'Failure sending mail.

Comment: I would need the rest of the error but i would imagine your username and password are not correct